# doing a group by within a group

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

i have two columns business_line(with values X,Y) and business_segment(values X,Y,Z same X and Y as business_line) in a table with name "Sometable". I have another column with name type_of_payment(with values A,B,C,D,E) and a final column with name transaction_value. This is what i want to do:

Sum the transactions grouped by business_line and business_segment and also find out what proportion of these payments were from A,C,E. So my output table would be something like this

```
                                             (last three columns can be named anything
                                              but they specify proportions of A,C,E)  
Business_line       SUM(transaction_value)   A        C        E
and business seg.
X                   100                      20%      30%      50%
Y                   200                      11%      12%      77%     
X                   300                        and so on
Y                   170
Z                   230
```

How do i do this??

PS : the sums of A C E need not be 100% as B and D are also present

Comment: have you looked at analytic functions?

Comment: i would like to do this using group by. I was thinking of a group by within a group by but dont know how to do it exactly. No idea about analytic functions.

Comment: Should the `A`,`C`,and `E` proportions always add up to 100%, even if there are `B` and `D` payments, and/or are the `B` and `D` payments included in the sum?

Comment: hmm ok i guess not .. not 100% will edit. nice observation

Comment: Which version of oracle?

Comment: erm just abv 11. want the exact version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is standard SQL, should work on Oracle (but untested):

```
SELECT
   business_line,
   business_segment,
   grand_total,
   A_total * 100.0 / grand_total as A,
   C_total * 100.0 / grand_total as C,
   E_total * 100.0 / grand_total as E
FROM
   (
       SELECT
          business_line,
          business_segment,
          SUM(transaction_value) as grand_total,
          SUM(CASE WHEN payment_type = 'A' THEN transaction_value END) as A_total,
          SUM(CASE WHEN payment_type = 'C' THEN transaction_value END) as C_total,
          SUM(CASE WHEN payment_type = 'E' THEN transaction_value END) as E_total
       FROM
          SomeTable
       GROUP BY
          business_line,
          business_segment
    ) as t
```

Comment: SUM(CASE WHEN payment_type = 'A' THEN transaction_value) as A_total .. i understand case statement but what is "THEN transaction_value" doing?

Comment: @ganducoder - I was missing the `END` part of the `CASE` statements (edited in now). Basically, each of those is ensuring that those `SUM()`s only include values where the `payment_type` matches the one we're interested in - so it's a conditional SUM of sorts. We can then use those totals in the outer select to compute a percentage.

Comment: k got it .. haven't tested it .. wont be able to for some time .. still accepting it as it seems to be logically correct

Answer (score 2):

For Oracle 11g and above, you can use `PIVOT`

```
select *
from
(
select sometable.line, paymenttype,total, 100.0*transaction_value/total as percentage
from sometable
    inner join
    (select line, sum(transaction_value) as total
        from sometable
        group by line) total
    on sometable.line = total.line          
) 
pivot 
(
    sum(percentage) for paymenttype in (a,c,e)
)
```